# Why the table view delegate methods don't get called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I found that my app built in **Release** configuration has sometimes an issue: the `tableView:heightForRowAt:` delegate method doesn't get called.

This issue is related to the build, for some builds, I always reproduce the issue, and for some other builds, I can never reproduce it.

When the issue happens, I can see that rows in my tableView get all 44 as height, and the break point that I made in `tableView:heightForRowAt:` method never get called.

[image: screenshots of normal and buggy result]

In my code I tried to use polymorphism in order to have 2 different implementations of table view data source and delegate methods. Here's a simplified example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableController: BaseTableController!

    let vm = ViewModel(sections: [...])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableController = VariantATableController(viewModel: vm)
        tableView.dataSource = tableController
        tableView.delegate = tableController
    }

}
class BaseTableController: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfSections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.sections[section].numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        fatalError("to be overridden")
    }    

}
class VariantATableController: BaseTableController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ACell", for: indexPath)
        let row = viewModel.sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = row.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = row.detail
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }

}
class VariantBTableController: BaseTableController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does it hit break point in release build when acting normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `tableView:heightForRowAt:` is defined in the base class and not just the derived classes. Otherwise it will be optimized out of the release build.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad before calling delegate and dataSource add below lines

```
tableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight=120
```

and add `estimatedHeightForRowAt` instead of `heightForRowAt`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

**Note**: To work with this you need to set auto layouts for cell properly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `tableView:heightForRowAt:` to the `class BaseTableController: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {}`.

`UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` is neccesary.